# Mount an image on a pdf in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am creating a signature with the react-native-signature-capture library and I want to be able to take this signature and place it on a pdf is this possible? Added to this I also need to be able to save this document, in what way could I do it? I think that taking a screenshot is not the right thing to do

Comment: did you found a solution ?